# Create separate GIT repository for publishing with different history?

Tags: git

I'm developing a project, which I'm pushing to private repository on my VPS. However, I'd like to publish it on GitHub.

I make a lot of commits(mostly as backups) which doesn't contain complete implementation of feature. I do not want to include history of these commits in public repo.

So, private history would look like:

1. Initial commit
2. Part Feature A
3. Part Feature A
4. Part Feature A
5. Finished Feature A
6. Part Feature B
7. Finished Feature B
8. ... etc ...

And desired history of public repo would look like:

1. Initial commit
2. Feature A
3. Feature B
4. ... etc ...

And **there must be no track about partial commits** made for development backup. So **all internals of a GIT repository would look like there were only just Feature commits**, no partial commits.

I know, that I can clone repositories to different folders, and copy-paste between these folders. However, GIT is designed for distributed development. So, I'm wondering whether there's some cleaner and more GIT-like way to solve this.

How to manage separate repositories with different histories?

The first commit on public repo can be completly squeezed, but since then I would like to have a nice commit history in public repo.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the multiple smaller commits in a private repo?

Comment: What's the actual reason for wanting to only expose completed features? If it's so people can easily check out specific *good* checkpoints, you could just tag the completed commits and otherwise leave everything as it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **[Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)**

Following this model, the `master` branch contains only releases, the `develop` branch contains the WIP (work in progress) commits, and `feature` branches are used to develop features.

The main benefit of this approach is, if you screw up and publish a bad commit to `develop` you'll be able to rollback the changes without screwing up the the history of the publicly accessible version on `master`.

So, that doesn't answer your question...

---

**What about combining partial features into a single feature commit?**

Simple, before merging a `feature` branch into `develop` squash the commits using interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i feature-branch
```

It'll pop up an editor and you can change which commits you want to squash. It also concats the commit logs so you can add all/part of them into the squashed commit message.

*Note: There are [many ways to squash commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/290340). IMHO, I think interactive rebase is the most straight-forward but YMMV.*

When you're ready for a release, simply create a `release` branch from `develop` and merge the `release` branch into `master.

---

Developing features can be challenging because a maintainer may require a contributor to make additional changes piecemeal prior to accepting a PR (pull request).

Using the strategy above, the contributor will still have a granular history containing all of the changes made to the feature throughout development. This makes it easy to roll-back and/or cherry-pick commits individually.

*Note: The ability to cherry-pick commits is extremely valuable if the contributor runs into complicated merge conflicts.*

If you want features to commit cleanly, simply have the contributor squash the changes as the last step prior to a merge.

Answer (score 0):

This begs the question of why you want to do that, but that is your problem. Here are some possible approaches to do that:

### Separate branches for features

- Keep your master branch in sync with master of the public repository
- develop each feature in your local / private repository, but do not sync these branches with the public repository
- use `git merge --squash` to merge these branches as a single commit

### Using different repositories

- Use a repository for public and private development
- develop in your private repository
- after a feature is done, use `git diff` to create a .diff file
- apply that diff using `patch` in the public repository and commit.

Comment: What does the first approach in "simple English"? "Converts branch (series of commits) to single commit?" Could you please provide step-by-step tutorial with explanation. Somehow, I don't get it :(

Comment: @Miro the "how do you do squash a series of commits into a single one" would be a question to ask on Stack Overflow instead. It delves a bit too deeply into the specifics of commands and the use of the tool rather than the higher level workflow.  See [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980).

Comment: @Miro This is an example for how squashing commits works, rebase or merge is more or less the same: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html